# Regular Expression(RegEx) not Validating the String "https://www.website"

Tags: regex, expression

I have a

```
RegExp = new RegExp(/^(((http|https|ftp|ftps):\/\/)[\w.-]+(?:\.[\w\.-]+)+[\w\-\._~:/?#[\]@!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=.])|((\\)(\\[A-Za-z0-9-_. ]+){2,}(\\?))$/);
```

This string - "https://www.website." To me, it should return False.

Working Scenarios:-

www.website.com (false)

http://website.com (true)

\UERERER\US_ER\2017\ (true)

Not working Scenario:

https://www.website. (This should return False, but here its returning true)

Kindly suggest

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are missing a "\" in the middle

test with :

```
^(((http|https|ftp|ftps):\/\/)[\w.-]+(?:\.[\w\.-]+)+[\w\-\._~:\/?#[\]@!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=.])|((\\)(\\[A-Za-z0-9-_. ]+){2,}(\\?))$
```